# UINavigationBar alpha set 0.909804 automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want a pure color navigationBar, so I call

```
let image = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.orange)
navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
```

`imageWithColor`method generate an image with pure color.

But the alpha of imageView is 0.909804.
[image: Result]

I set another image to try again.
[image: Result]

I know `translucent = false` would solve this problem, but it will change the view's layout.

Is there any way to set a opaque navigationBar without setting the translucent = false?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this problem in imageWithColor method.

Comment: if you need to set single colr then you can set barTintColor property of naviagationBar.

Comment: What do you mean: _but it will change the view's layout_?

Answer (score 1):

You can change background color of navigationBar

```
navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in this method **imageWithColor**

**Replace this line :**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size); // check this line in fuction
```

**With**

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

i made a function to achieve this and in default/outlet navigation bar i set pure color with this image and it's working fine for me.

```
func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: 
size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

One more try with this one. call like this.

```
let image = self.getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.orange, size: 
UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, 
for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `AppDelegate.swift`, add this line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Then, in your viewController `viewDidLoad`, add this line:

```
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

That should give you an Opaque Navigation Bar that behaves like a Translucent one.

Comment: Actually，my project use both translucent and opaque navigation bar，there is something wrong when an opaque UIViewController push to a translucent UIViewController. 

Comment: Is this a different problem than the one in your original question?